# WSO2 IoT 3.0.0 unable to register a device

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

When I enroll my first Android device, I am able to install the agent and configure the server. I have no error about linking Android Agent to WSO2 IoT Server.

On the Android device I get an error : " Enrollement Failed : Enrollment failed, please contact administrator."

This error is with the user I created with the role admin and also with the admin account.

The communication is in HTTP because I do not have a signed certificate. I am looking for a solution for 2 days.

Contact me by email to receive account information from my test server.

Best regards

Tof

Comment: which port did you try to connect with(8280/9443) ?

Comment: I'm connect to 9763 port. I followed the documentation
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS300/Android  Because I am in http and not in https
Http = 9763
Https = 9443

Comment: @Tof: Did you just download the agent which comes with the IoT server or compiled and built apk from the source? Also, from IoT 3.0 onwards, default http port that is used to communicate with the server is 8280. So http = 8280, https = 8243.

Comment: @mharindu : Hello and thank you for your help, I will test but why in many file in /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/devicemgt and /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/android-web-agent , It is indicated the port http = 9763 and the https: 9443?

Comment: @Tof: From IoTs 3.0.0 onwards, all the internal APIs are getting published to (internal) WSO2 API Manager which comes with the product itself. Hence the default API gateway ports of the product are 8280 and 8243.

Answer (score 0):

From **IoT 3.0.0** onwards, default http port that is used to communicate with the server is `8280`.
Starting from IoTs 3.0.0, all the internal APIs are getting published to (internal) WSO2 API Manager which comes with the product itself. 
Hence the default API gateway ports of the product are 8280 (http) and 8243 (https).

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your reply. I want to understand but you are that the ports that you announced are good for tablets and smartphones?
Here are the files that are always with port 9443 (https) in iot 3.0.0 and iot 3.1.0 (Jenkins):
- /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/configs/designer.json
- /repository/conf/app-manager.xml (localhost: 9443 / ssmslo)
- /repository/conf/api-manager.xml
- And much more

I recall that it is just to record a smartphone or a tablet

Comment: I tested with port 8280 and it works! But I do not understand because in several configuration files, there is still port 9443 for the https and 9763 for the http. Can someone explain?

For this to work, I have to modify "host": "% http.ip%", by http: // myip: 8280 in the files: /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/devicemgt/app/conf/config.json and /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/android-web-agent/app/conf/config.json